# Identifying is a string is a substring of another longer one in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a search function on my page. The page will by default load a list of items. I implemented a search box above the table, and upon clicking the search button, the table will reload with only those values that apply with the search string.

I have ListOfStrings ([]) which is the list of all entries in the table, and searchString is what the user will enter in the search box. So, the logic should be that all entries in ListOfStrings that have searchString as a substring should be displayed. I am implementing logic as follows,

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchString">
    <input type="button" value="Search Text" ng-click="reloadTable()">
</form>

var reloadTable = function()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < ListOfStrings.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((searchString) && (ListOfStrings[i].indexOf(searchString) != -1)) 
        {                         
            ListToDisplay.push(ListOfStrings[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have the following problems,

1. Apparently, my search criteria is not case insensitive. ListOfStrings are all in upper case. So unless searchString is also in upper case, the if case won't work. So, how do I implement that logic to be case insensitive?
2. Another functionality I want is that if after searching once, the user clears searchString and clicks on the search button, the entire list should be displayed. However, with my code, if the searchString is cleared in the UI, its value is still being read as something other than null (I guess), and that is messing with populating ListToDisplay. Nothing is being pushed into ListToDisplay. How do I implement that functionality?

Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said your list is already all in uppercase, so simply convert `searchString` to upper before you loop:

```
searchString = searchString.toUpperCase();
```

The value of an input field will never be `null`, but it can be an empty string (`""`). So in the case of an empty string just copy the whole list instead of looping:

```
searchString = searchString.toUpperCase();
if (searchString === "") {
  ListToDisplay = ListOfStrings;
  // or ListToDisplay = ListOfStrings.slice(); if you want to take a copy
} else {
  ListToDisplay = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ListOfStrings.length; i++) {
    if (ListOfStrings[i].indexOf(searchString) != -1) {
      ListToDisplay.push(ListOfStrings[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

But rather than looping and `.push()`ing I'd just use the [array `.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
searchString = searchString.toUpperCase();
ListToDisplay = !searchString ? ListOfStrings : ListOfStrings.filter(function(el) {
    return el.indexOf(searchString) != -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert everything to the same case before comparing.
2. I think you need to share a bit more of the relevant code; all you have shared so far is for comparisons.